# How to know which booleans are true inside If statement in JS?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I want to know if `if` statement is true then which **booleans are true inside the condition**?

I mean I have this code:

```js
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = true;

if (a || b || c) {
   alert('Here I want to alert a and c. Because they are true.');
}
```

I think I can do it with `for` or `while`. For example checking all variables again inside `if` statement, but can I do it with less code or more efficient way?

Comment: You don't need to use `for` or `while`, you can just check again with `if`.

Comment: @rid But, I should check every of variables inside ```if```. What if I have 15 or more variables?

Comment: In this particular case, it's not necessary to check if `a || b || c`, you can check directly if `a` is `true`, then append to the string you want to alert, then check `b`, etc. If you have an object or an array of booleans, then you can use a loop instead.

Comment: If you have 15 or more variable then you should use array and you can use some truth filter from lodash or underscore

Comment: ... or just use JavaScript's built in [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function if you don't want a library just to filter an array. Still, both the array and the object have many functions that can help, if you have the option of getting your values structured some way other than a variable for each.

Comment: @rid, MunirKhakhi |  Ok, I will add all them to array and then will check it. I hoped there was more simple way, but anyway. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ahmedg "more simple way", well that's the most simple way ever.

Comment: @ahmedg  If you want to maintain the key(varname), Objects are even simpler..

Comment: @ahmedg For unknown number of variables, you won't know their names...  If that's important, you'll have to code for that, then you can use `((a)?("a "):("")` for each and accumulate results (`"True variables: "+((a)?("a "):("")+((b)?("b "):("")+((c)?("c "):("")`).  Otherwise, you can use an array.  If more than one place or to re-use, may I suggest writing a function?  The function could get a list that you evaluate over the args array, or an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put your values inside an object, things are a little easier.

You can use Object.values, Object.enteries etc..

eg.

```js
var obj = {
 a: true,
 b: false,
 c: true
};

if (Object.values(obj).some(Boolean)) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    if (v) console.log(k);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the if-statements in 3 parts.

```js
if (a) { 
    alert("your message for a");
}
if (b) { alert("your message for b"); }
if (c) { alert("your message for c"); }
```

The statements will be executed only if a,b or c are true. In that way you know which ones are true.

Another way -for when you have lots of variables- is to use loops. You can put your variables inside an array,. Then you will check every index of the table.
You can find more info here:[https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp_](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.reduce` for at the same time process the final boolean value and display the value that are true.

```js
const a = true;
const b = false;
const c = true;

const arr = [{ a }, { b }, { c }]; // put them in an array

const ret = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const name = Object.keys(curr)[0];
  if (curr[name]) { console.log(name, 'is true'); }
  return acc || curr[name];
}, false);

if (ret) {
  // do something here
}
```